# Deep Learning: which kind of layer for {time_series + static} -> time_series problems?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, time-series, transformer

as you can see in the image below, I need to bridge static data (on the left) and time series data (on the right) to create a time series output. I have looked at this [example](https://keras.io/examples/timeseries/timeseries_transformer_classification/) on keras library which deals with `transformers` but to no avail. generally what are the layers that are used to solve:

**time_series + static -> time_series**

would the "core" of the answer change if it were (=core maybe you keep the same framework and then you just pick the latest value or "reduction" of some kind):
**time_series + static -> static**

[image]

here the time series part is more "features" based on time that changes and I would avoid using RNN/LSTM or the sort as much as possible. it's just a matter of concatenating things without resulting in not exploding my features and therefore adding "bias" to the problem

p.s.: I know there are some [custom solutions for this problem](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/99795/transforming-time-series-into-static-features) but here I need to deal with transforming/concatenating things as I will add multiple sources like this (this is a simple example) and I need a general way to deal with this kind of aggregation problem (feeding everything to a single RNN will not do)

Comment: Why an algorithm like random forest would'nt solve your problem? Does an adapted data pre processing to scale the features correctly between each other would be the key?

Comment: because I might have multiple data sources that would generate some multiplication of features {users} X {products} X {time_series_users} X {time_series_products}X {time_series_other} -> ideally I would crunch this in a smart fashion

Comment: In that case, is it possible to weight each feature so that they can be classified correctly? I mean that some features can be common to lot of data sources, the other ones can be included but with some mathematical operations to be correctly weighted between each other.

Comment: what do you mean? could you give a simple but practical example?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you had heterogeneous data sources, but no: you just have several sources that you want to group in one. In your case, it could be meaningful to make a time series model for each main feature (one for the users, and one for the products) with the right time scale (one user bought 5 products in one month). If you want to do multiple time series with different times features, it is also possible but maybe a time simplification (ex: convert to day or weeks) could be more interesting to group data better.